# Terminology and references for Jordan's lemma for unitary representations

Tags: matrices, representation-theory, matrix-decomposition, projection-matrices, unitary-matrices

The statement I'm interested in (ambiguously named Jordan's lemma) concerns the setting where knowing that $A^2 = B^2 = I$ for two unitary matrices, for instance, ensures a decomposition of the vector space on which $A, B$ act into $A, B$-invariant subspaces with block size at most 2.

I'm interested in understanding how group-relations among unitary representations of finite groups affect the decomposition of an underlying vector space on which these representations act into invariant subspaces. [This post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328574/generalization-of-jordans-lemma-a2-b2-i-can-be-2-block-diagonalized) mentions some of these topics, but does not provide strong references. What are good treatments (e.g., textbooks)?